# Asp.Net - Adding a £ sign to price when using Bind, Correct Syntax?

Tags: asp.net, bind

Just a quick one.. I had this code written for me, it works but I need to add a £ sign at the front of postage. So for example it will output £2.99 instead of 2.99

```
<asp:Label ID="lblPostage" visible="true" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" Text='<%# Bind("postage") %>' />
```

I've tried doing this but no luck..

```
<asp:Label ID="lblPostage" visible="true" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" Text='£' & '<%# Bind("postage") %>' />
```

Comment: Its been a long time since I looked at web forms but does this work? `Text="£<%# Bind("postage") %>"`

Comment: @AshleyMedway Not quite, I think it needs to be single quotes somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this in the end by changing the 'Bind' to 'Eval' and then doing this..

```
Text='<%# "+£" & Eval("postage") & " P&P" %>'
```